# Why is my app_home_opened event sometimes triggered twice?

Tags: slack-api

I subscribed my bot to the following event: https://api.slack.com/events/app_home_opened

It works and the event is triggered when you open/focus the chat (DM) channel with the bot as it should. However, sometimes (not always) the event is triggered twice and I don't know why.

Interesting is that the second event can appear a few seconds (~2-3 seconds) later than the first one without me switching windows or anything.

I use the following adapter from Slack:
https://github.com/slackapi/node-slack-events-api

And this is how my code looks like:

```
slackEvents.on('app_home_opened', (event: any, body: any) => {
  if (body.token !== process.env.SLACK_VERIFICATION_TOKEN) return;

  console.log('App home opened event: ', event);
  console.log('App home opened body: ', body);

  BotMessageInterpreter.handleAppHomeOpenedMessage(app, messagesDB, body);
});
```

This is the event and body data sent from Slack. I removed the sensitive information, but controlled that everything is identical except the event_id and event_ts.

```
// First event
App home opened event:  
{ 
  type: 'app_home_opened',
  user: 'my-slack-id',
  channel: 'my-channel-id' 
}

App home opened body:  { 
  token: 'my-token',
  team_id: 'my-team-id',
  api_app_id: 'the-api-app-id',
  event:
  { 
    type: 'app_home_opened',
    user: 'my-slack-id',
    channel: 'my-channel-id' 
  },
  type: 'event_callback',
  event_id: 'EvKHQ2G7NU',
  event_time: 1560409852 
}

// Second event
App home opened event:  
{ 
  type: 'app_home_opened',
  user: 'my-slack-id',
  channel: 'my-channel-id' 
}

App home opened body:  
{ 
  token: 'my-token',
  team_id: 'my-team-id',
  api_app_id: 'the-api-app-id',
  event:
  { 
    type: 'app_home_opened',
    user: 'my-slack-id',
    channel: 'my-channel-id' 
  },
  type: 'event_callback',
  event_id: 'EvKKU0U6CE',
  event_time: 1560409840 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems this can be avoided by checking numbers of retries in the header:

```
if (headers['x-slack-retry-num']) return;
```